# How to save image file, using "xfce4-screenshooter -r -c" command?

Tags: terminal, image-processing, xfce4

I using `xfce4-screenshooter -r -c` command for make a screenshot.

`xfce4-screenshooter --help` says:

> **-c, --clipboard**  Copy the screenshot to the clipboard
>
> **-r, --region**  Select a region to be captured by  clicking a point of the screen without releasing the mouse button, dragging your mouse to the other corner of the region, and releasing the mouse button.

Ok. How to save screenshot to the file.png from clipboard? What's tool can helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem so:
I using `xclip` for work with my clipboard

```
apt install xclip
```

I typed:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -o > /home/user/image.png
```

...and image file from clipboard (xfce4-screenshooter -r -c) has been created on my user folder.

Hope it helps somebody!